# Cannot compile basic actor example in Scala

Tags: eclipse, scala

I'm trying to compile the example from [the official guide](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242), the one with the ping pong.
I've put the Ping and Pong classes in their own files, in the default package. However, the Ping class has compilation errors, saying it cannot find the Pong class, and vice versa. I also tried to clean the project so that a rebuild will happen, but I cannot make any progresses. I am using the final version of 2.8.1, from [here](http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-wip-exp-backport-2.8.1.final).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full source for pingpong.scala can be found in [scala-2.8.1.final-sources.tgz](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-2.8.1.final-sources.tgz)

Location in tgz: scala-2.8.1.final-sources/docs/examples/actors/pingpong.scala

The example assumes all the classes are in the same file and can be compiled with

```
scalac pingpong.scala
```

But if you wanted to put them in separate files:

Ping.scala

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

case object Ping
class Ping(count: Int, pong: Actor) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    var pingsLeft = count - 1
    pong ! Ping
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case Pong =>
          if (pingsLeft % 1000 == 0)
            Console.println("Ping: pong")
          if (pingsLeft > 0) {
            pong ! Ping
            pingsLeft -= 1
          } else {
            Console.println("Ping: stop")
            pong ! Stop
            exit()
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pong.scala

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

case object Pong
class Pong extends Actor {
  def act() {
    var pongCount = 0
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case Ping =>
          if (pongCount % 1000 == 0)
            Console.println("Pong: ping "+pongCount)
          sender ! Pong
          pongCount = pongCount + 1
        case Stop =>
          Console.println("Pong: stop")
          exit()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

pingpong.scala

```
case object Stop

object pingpong extends Application {
  val pong = new Pong
  val ping = new Ping(100000, pong)
  ping.start
  pong.start
}
```

and then run scalac *.scala

Comment: Thank you! After reading through your sources I realized I forgot to add the case objects.